# Gap between DIVs AND floating FOOTER

Tags: html, css

I know this (or a variant) has been asked a lot... but nothing I have seen pertains to what I am dealing with here.

I still have a 14px gap between vertical DIV elements. When I inspect the page, it is not accounted for (nothing highlighted). It goes from one div (with no margin or padding at the bottom) to the next (with no margin or padding at the top).

The only solution I have come up with so far is to set the margin of the lower DIV to -14px, but I feel like that should't be necessary.

Also, my FOOTER is floating in the middle of the screen!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- navigation -->
    </header>
    <main>

        <div class="banner">
            <div>
                <h3>Some text</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, eius.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="services-section">
            <p>
                These are services
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-section">
            <p>
                This is content
            </p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <ul>
            <li>something
            <li>something else
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
html,body,main
{
    height: 100%;

}

footer
{
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    min-height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner
{
    background: url('/img/laptop.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.banner div
{
    /* padding-top: 200px;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner div h3
{
    font-size: 36px;
    text-shadow: 0em 0.1em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.banner div p
{
    font-size: 18px;

}

.services-section
{
    background-color: #eee;
    min-height: 520px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.contact-section
{
    background-color: #1C74BB;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

fiddlen https://jsfiddle.net/1vLzvb0k/9/

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space is coming from `p` tag.
Add `margin:0` in stylesheet

```
p{
    margin:0
}
```

```css
html,body,main {
     height: 100%;
}
footer {
     background-color: #000;
     color: white;
     min-height: 120px;
     width: 100%;
}
 .banner {
     background: url('/img/laptop.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     color: white;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
}
 .banner div {
    /* padding-top: 200px;
    */
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     width: 100%;
}
 .banner div h3 {
     font-size: 36px;
     text-shadow: 0em 0.1em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
 .banner div p {
     font-size: 18px;
}
 .services-section {
     background-color: #eee;
     min-height: 520px;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 
}
 .contact-section {
     background-color: #1C74BB;
     min-height: 400px;
}
 p{
     margin:0 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <!-- navigation -->
      </header>
      <main>
         <div class="banner">
            <div>
               <h3>Some text</h3>
               <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, eius.
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="services-section">
            <p>
               These are services
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="contact-section">
            <p>
               This is content
            </p>
         </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
         <ul>
            <li>something
            <li>something else
         </ul>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, how did you see that? When I apply margin 0 to THAT particular P tag it works. If I apply that to ALL P tags, it doesn't work... any idea why this happens?

Comment: I applied `margin:0` to all `p` tag in above snippet, I need to see your actual code before I can suggest anything.

Comment: I just added a "reset" ( *{margin: 0 !important} ) - that works well. Thank. It is just confusing because no margin or padding was showing in any debug tool. Not sure if I would have ever thought to check the P tag!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Any idea why my FOOTER tag is in the middle of the page?

Comment: remove this style `html, body, main {    height: 100%;}`

Comment: I need that for the banner parallax

Comment: I hope you have already figured it out, if not remove `html, body` from this style leave only `main {height: 100%}`, also don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: You did lead in a direction where I could work it out, though.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.banner div
        {
            /* padding-top: 200px;*/
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

to

```
div.banner
        {
            /* padding-top: 200px;*/
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

and you want to set banner on top remove `position:absolute;`

Comment: .banner div refers to the DIV inside the banner element. div.banner would only refer to the banner element. Would make no difference.

Comment: besides, the div inside the banner element isn't the problem. it works the way I want it to.